# Expresión regular - match después de una palabra exacta sin espacios ni caracteres especiales

Tags: regex

estoy intentando hacer un match a través del uso de expresiones regulares, para comprobantes de proveedores (facturas - invoices).

Necesito que el match sea con los números que se encuentran a la derecha de "Importe Total:" sin espacios ni el signo $.

Hace ya dos días que vengo trabado con esto, que estimo no es complicado, pero soy nuevo.

Consulta:

```
 - Importe Total: $ 4900,00
 - Importe Total:  $4900,00 
 - Importe Total:$4900    
 - Importe Total: $      4900

Resultado esperado: 

 - 4900,00 
 - 4900,00 
 - 4900,00 
 - 4900,00
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
$ 4900,00
$4900,00 
$4900    
$      4900
```

Utilicé varias fórmulas, pero en todas obtuve el valor junto con los espacios y el signo $.

Les dejo la última que usé:

`(?<=Importe\sTotal:)(.*?\d.*(?=[^\S]))`

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Saca el `.*?` del grupo, y tampoco veo la necesidad del otro grupo anidado `(?<=Importe\sTotal:).*?(\d+)`

Comment: Gracias, continúa sin funcionarme. Y al ponerlo así, tampoco trae los decimales. Eso ya lo pude resolver agrando ```,\d+``` a la expresión que me mandaste.

Comment: En qué lenguaje o en qué herramienta?? La respuesta varía mucho dependiendo de qué librería de regex sea.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar asumiendo que son cantidades numericas:

```
/(?<=Importe\sTotal:)\s*\$?\s*(\d+,?\d*)/gm
```

Lo cual se representa como:

[image: maquina de estados]

Como ver[as el grupo de captura numero 1 siempre tendras el valor que necesitas

```js
const regex = /(?=Importe\sTotal:)\s*\$?\s*(\d+,?\d*)/gm;
const str = `- Importe Total: \$ 4900,00
 - Importe Total:  \$4900,00 
 - Importe Total:\$4900    
 - Importe Total: \$      4900`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```